# How can i position the view of an android app?

Tags: android, cordova

Hi I'm working on an an android app with phonegap and I'm currently trying to adjust the view size for different mobile/tablet devices. For one resolution instead of stretching the view to each corner of the screen i'd like to have the view in the center of the screen so that there is an even amount of extra black space bordering between the view and the screens edge. I've read somethings about layoutparam and linearlayout but I'm not quite sure what to do with those.

Answer (score 0):

Did you hear about responsive web design? Also you can use a framework like jQuery mobile

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design